# How do I fix a Problem With Calling methods in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

[Whenever I try to call a method such as "name.", it stops me at the . and gives me an error message. Ant help?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPUbo.jpg)

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: In your image you don't have a variable called `index` so an error here is correct.

Comment: Looks like an outdated Eclipse. Especially if you have updated macOS to Big Sur but missed to update Eclipse, you will face a couple of issues.

Comment: I had installed JFrame in eclipse for one of my classes and that's when I noticed the problem but reinstalling worked somehow even though I had the most recent eclipse version. Thank you!